Using data and equations from published work
I am currently writing my thesis and in my literature review, I (multiple times) used data and equations from previously published work to create figures and tables. In the case of figures, some of them are close to the original (same (approximate) data, same equations) but are clearly different in their form with added details.
I always explicitly cite the paper's full name and the (first) authors when I use the data. But, I've heard from some colleagues that I could get in trouble for not getting copyright permissions. Some other colleagues are less worried and claim that I should not get in trouble as long as I don't completely copy (screenshot and paste) the figures.
I know that the question has been asked quite a lot here but every post seems to contradict the others, could someone clarify?

You are probably ok with the equations, though it is a bit subtle. As stated here (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/copyright-of-mathematical-formulas), ideas aren't copyrightable, only creative expression. And if an idea has only one expression then even that expression isn't copyrightable. And mathematical formulae capture ideas in a standardized format.
Note that the purpose of copyright and other IP laws is to extend scholarship, not limit it, while permitting creators to benefit from the creation. That is why copyright and patent have limited terms and expire. So, ideas can be used by anyone, even when they are found in copyrighted material. And, "fair use" implies that you can use and restate unique representations of those ideas as there may be no other way to express them.
In any case, the use of ideas isn't limited by copyright.
You need to cite the source of ideas, of course, but you know that already.
The data is a different issue, but if you use it, rather than republishing it, you should, again, be fine. Cite the source, of course.

Thanks for the answer @Buffy!
